# SQL: sum(unit) table a minus sum(unit) table b

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have 2 tables;

1. item_in(item_id,unit)
2. item_out(item_id,unit)

Now let say I want to know how many unit is being insert for every item, I just query

```
select sum(unit) from item_in order by item_id
```

Likewise, if I want to know how many unit is being taken out, I just query

```
select sum(unit) from item_out order by item_id
```

I don't know how to query the balance (item_in - item_out) for each item.

It is great if I can make all the query in one stored procedure, because I want to call the procedure using DataWindow.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Are there items that appear in the item_in and not in the item_out. And viceversa?

Comment: yes, there is the probability that an item never taken out. I've tried your answers, but no success. i used left outer join because full outer join produce error. somemore, it's t1.unit - t2.unit. but that's also doesn't work. it seems the result is doubled from the expected result.

Comment: but no, if the item is in the item_out, that's mean it's in item_in before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  SUM(unit) AS unit_balance
FROM (
  SELECT item_id, unit FROM item_in
  UNION ALL
  SELECT item_id, -unit FROM item_out
) AS s (item_id, unit)
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! I tried this query at MySQL and success, I think Sybase should not have any problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this query won't work on Sybase. It seems Sybase expecting a table name after FROM.

Comment: @Iyas: Are you sure you added an alias after the subselect, like in my example (`s`)? I would be surprised if Sybase didn't support subselects in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Iyas: According to [this manual page](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315738.htm), subselects in FROM clauses should be fine.

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Error Code:
156

Query = SELECT
  drug_id,
  SUM(quantity) AS unit_balance
FROM
(
  SELECT drug_id, quantity FROM t_item_in
  UNION
ALL
  SELECT drug_id, -quantity FROM t_item_out
) s
GROUP
BY drug_id`

Comment: @Iyas: [They say](http://www.dbforums.com/sybase/1653794-sub-query-clause.html) subselects are not supported prior to Sybase 12.5, so if it's your case, my suggestion will not help you here, sorry. (And you should then unaccept my answer probably so we do not mislead people.) But maybe it's just that I got the syntax wrong. According to the same manual page, correlation names for subselects should be declared a bit differently in Sybase. (I was hoping at first it was always the same as in SQL Server which I am more acquainted with.). Updated my answer.

Comment: The updated answer also doesn't work. I guess the work around is to set a view. then select from the view.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about sybase, but this, or a subtle variation of this, should work.

```
select t1.item_id, sum(t1.unit - coalesce(t2.unit, 0)) as Balance
from item_in t1
left join item_out t2
on t1.item_id = t2.item_id
group by t1.item_id
```

Coalesce will put a 0 whenever a unit from t2 is NULL, so that you can properly substract the item_in unit amount from it.

Note: This works in SQL Server. I don't know if you might find any syntactic difference when running it in sybase :(

Comment: Your query is so close to I what expected. Just some item, got it right, some item has near double the result. eg. expected 2344, but got 4123, something like that.

Comment: Please, run it again as I updated the query many times :) Run it now (I'm not updating it anymore)

Comment: I'm at home right now. do not have access to Sybase. but I tried your query in MySQL. My sample data have 200 unit in item_in, and 50 unit in item_out for the same item_id which we should expect a balance of 150. Your query produce 300, which is double the expected value. Anyway, I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i hope the following query works:

```
select 
sum(inn.unit) - sum(outt.unit)
from item_in inn
inner join item_out outt on inn.item_id = outt.item_id
```

Comment: your query is missing group by inn.item_id, outt.item_id

Comment: but same as Mosty Mostacho, some item get double result.